# Sets, that have $\operatorname{LCM}\left(|c_1|,\dots,|c_p|\right)=\sum_{k=1}^p |c_k|$

Tags: number-theory, notation, symmetric-groups

I found that the least common multiple of the sizes of conjugacy classes $c_k$ of the symmetric group $S_n$ is equivalent to $n!$ the order of the group.
Equivalently the sum of all $c_k$ is also $n!$. I checked $n<7$ and $n=8$.

So we have $\operatorname{LCM}\biggr(|c_1|,\dots,|c_p|\biggr)=\sum_{k=1}^p |c_k|$. Do these sets of integers $\{|c_k|\}$ have a special name and further properties, occurences or application?

**EDIT**

The sets of divisors of perfect numbers would fit, since *e.g.* 
$$\operatorname{LCM}\biggr(1,2,7,14\biggr)=28=1+2+4+7+14,$$
therefore a related question is this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/495802/19341).

Comment: I also [checked](http://aleph.sagemath.org/?q=msbmto) $A_4, \cdots, A_8$ and $D_5, D_7$ have the same property.

Comment: I believe that groups that satisfy this property are called "full index" groups.One necessary condition for this to hold is that the group center must be trivial:
: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~rdc26/forkpshum.pdf

Comment: @Taro thanks for this great link...

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks for this very interesting paper...