# Are there groups with conjugacy classes as large as the divisors of perfect numbers?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

Are there groups, where the conjugacy classes have elements according to the divisors of perfect numbers larger than $6$?

I already got the first example, so therefore $6$ is excluded: $S_3$.

The corresponding [GroupProps page on groups of order $28$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_28) is still empty, but [OEIS/A000001](http://oeis.org/A000001) says that there are $4$ groups having $28$ elements.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little bit better? What does it mean "elements according to the the divisors of perfect numbers"??

Comment: @SteveD let me work out the "group of order 28" example: I'm asking if there is group with conjugacy classes having $1,2,4,7$ and $14$ elements.

Comment: Oh ok: then the answer is no. If $4$ divides the order of the group $G$ (let's say $|G|=n$), then there cannot be an element whose conjugacy class has size $n/2$.  This is because such an element would be order $2$ and self-centralizing, which is impossible (normalizers grow in p-groups).

Comment: @SteveD so 6 is the only example...?

Comment: @draks... As far as I know it's not proven that there are no odd perfect numbers.

Comment: @DanielFischer do you think, it's possible to (dis)prove that a corresponding group exists?

Comment: I believe you can also rule out the odd perfect number case (assuming they might exist) using the same type of argument, replacing "normalizers grow" with "center of a p-group is non-trivial".  Then you can show each prime dividing $|G|$ divides it only once, etc.

Comment: @draks done; let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $|G|=n$, and that $n$ is a perfect number, with $G$ having a conjugacy class of every possible size. Let's show $n=6$.

First, let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $n$, and let $x\in G$ be an element with conjugacy class size $n/p$. Then $C_G(x)$ has size $p$, so $x$ is an element of order $p$ that is self-centralizing. Since $N_G(\langle x\rangle)/C_G(\langle x\rangle)$ has order dividing $p-1$, the minimality of $p$ implies $N_G(\langle x\rangle)=C_G(\langle x\rangle)$. Thus $G$ has a normal $p$-complement, so that $G=H\rtimes \langle x\rangle$, with $|H|=n/p$.

Now let $y\in H$ have a conjugacy class size of $p$.  Then the centralizer of $y$ has order $|H|$, so $y\in Z(H)$. This means that if $|y|=k$, then every element in $H$ has centralizer at least of order $k$, so conjugacy class size dividing $n/k$.  Since we want conjugacy classes of every possible size, this is only possible if $n/k=p$, or $n=kp$. In particular, $H$ is cyclic with generator $y$.

But then the only possible conjugacy classes are those in $H$ of size $p$, and those outside $H$ of size $n/p=k$.  Thus $k$ must be a prime $q$, and $n=pq$.  By the assumption that $n$ is perfect, $pq=p+q+1$. Since $p<q$, working mod $q$ shows
$$ p+1=q.$$

Thus $p=2$, $q=3$, and $n=6$.

Comment: This argument also shows $G$ must be $S_3=C_3\rtimes C_2$.

Comment: thanks, it just took me some time to get through the first part...